# MAUI - What would be a proper equivalent to WPF's ListView + GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

I am exploring `MAUI` by migrating an existing WPF application. Most of the functionality seems to be portable into MAUI however I am not sure how I can replicate the `ListView` / `GridView` functionality.

Here is what I had in my WPF application:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModel.IotHubMessages}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Correlation ID" 
                Width="100"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CorrelationId}" 
                />
             ...
         <GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I know there are `CollectionView` / `ListView` concepts in MAUI but none of them provide a similar tabular UI with header.

**Question**

How can I display data in a Grid format with proper headers using MAUI?

Comment: The omission is probably because xamarin started out mobile, and mobile devices are usually small - so a full "table" layout wasn't practical. `CollectionView` does have a `Header`. I don't recall whether that scrolls off the top or not. Might need to build manually, with `<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *"> <... Grid.Row="0" ...> <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ><CollectionView.ItemTemplate><Grid ... >`. (ListView is a legacy layout; I would use CollectionView instead.)

Comment: TableView with view cells? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/tableview